# To get value from regex expression on my input and not the location from my specific python code

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I have an input excel file which I have converted to pandas dataframe column on which I am using a regex expression to get the values but what I am getting is the location.

Adding input file image with requirement:

[input file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AY3K.png)

Requirement as per image:

```
Email                         Order
testuser@xyz.com      1-1155945200890,1-1152015113839
```

What i am getting from my code:

```
Email                         Order
testuser@xyz.com      [<filter object at 0x000002900BD628D0>]
```

Code for definition of feedback:

```
for user in users:
    intent_name=data_to_analyse2.loc[data_to_analyse2['USERID'] ==  user]
    intent_list=list(intent_name['INTENTNAME'])
    feedback=list(intent_name['Input'])     #taking data from input column
```

Below is the code which I was running and writing it to a csv file

```
T_Order=[]
Appointment=[]

order=re.compile("1[\-][\d]{2,15}")

order_list=filter(order.match, feedback)


if 'T Order' in feedback:
    T_Order.append(order_list)

if 'Appointment' in feedback:
    Appointment.append(order_list)

try:
    T_order_count=len(T_Order[0])
except:
    T_order_count=0

try:
    Appointment_count=len(Appointment[0])
except:
    Appointment_count=0
```

But I need values instead of location. Please help me where I am doing it wrong and how to fix this.

Comment: What is the format of the dataframe column in question?

Comment: `order_list` is a generator. Convert it to a list with `list(order_list)` before appending to the lists. As a side note, do not use exceptions where an `if` statement can be used.

Comment: @CinCout added input column

Comment: @DYZ thanks for ur response..tried converting to list function however getting error as :
    order_list=list(filter(order.match, feedback))
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Use `order=re.compile(rb"1-\d{2,15}$")`, then `order_list=list(filter(order.match, feedback))`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Tried using your solution but the issue persists getting location only not the value:  
[<filter object at 0x000002E19528EBE0>]
[<filter object at 0x000002E19528E668>]

Comment: Then please provide the contents of `feedback` as it is shown in the console.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I have updated the question with the input columns and how I had defined feedback. let me know if i did something wrong for which it is giving the location only and not value

Comment: That method is not helpful. What are the *contents*? Dump them and add a sample to the question.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I have added image input file, sample output what is required from it and what I am getting right now. Any help or leads would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`filter` returns a lazy object which only performs calculations when you iterate on it. You can transform it into a concrete list using the `list` function. So, your code will look like this (I took the liberty of refactoring a bit):

```
T_Order = []
Appointment = []

order = re.compile("1[\-][\d]{2,15}")
order_list = list(filter(order.match, feedback))

if 'T Order' in feedback:
    T_Order.append(order_list)
if 'Appointment' in feedback:
    Appointment.append(order_list)

T_order_count = len(T_Order[0]) if T_Order else 0
Appointment_count = len(Appointment[0]) if Appointment else 0
```

Comment: thanks for your response...i tried transforming order_list to a list function however I am getting an error now as: 
    order_list=list(filter(order.match, feedback))
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I have added image input file, sample output what is required from it and what I am getting right now. Any help or leads would be appreciated